# calculating angled distances across a square

Tags: java, geometry

Given a point in a square I need to calculate how far that point is across the square (0% progress at one end, 100% at the other).  For simple horizontal (or vertical) traversals the progress is just the X-coordinate (or Y-coordinate) divided by the size of the square.

But here's where I'm struggling:  I need the traversal to be at an angle, so a few (degrees?  radians?) either slanting up or down.  If this helps: all the points with matching "progress" values, should form a line perpendicular to the path/angle of traversal.

I need to write a method like this (most any language), that returns a value between 0 and 1:

```
float calculateProgress(float x, float y, float size, float angle) { }
```

... but not sure where to start.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Edit/Added Description: for a flat/horizontal traversal, the points that report "50% progress" would form a vertical line in the middle of the square.  But rotated a little counter-clockwise, I want those same points (now rotated to form a slanting line) to report "50% progress" even though the top half are now to the left of x/size and the bottom half are now to the right of x/size.

Comment: You could lessen your struggles by programming in a single language.  Combining C++ and Java increases the complexity of a program.

Comment: Tags should be used when they're _specifically_ relevant to your question. If your question is not specific to any language, it shouldn't have a language tag. If it's just a math question, it shouldn't be on SO altogether.

Comment: Given those parameters, how do you know where the square is?

Comment: Your requirements do not make sense. Starting at (0,0) of a 10x10 square at 10 degrees, a progress value of 0.5 would occur at x=.5. Starting at (0,1) at the same angle, a progress value of 0.5 would also occur at x=5. These values would form a line perpendicular to the x axis, not to the path.

Comment: My mistake forgetting to mention screen coordinates!  It's a square image on the screen, (0,0) in the upper-left corner, (size-1,size-1) in the lower-right corner.  Apologies also for the confusing tags, just grabbed the 2 languages I'm most familiar with.  This particular app is in Java.

Comment: You can calculate intersection points between line and square edges [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542004/how-to-calculate-the-distance-from-a-given-point-on-the-surface-of-a-square-to-i/47543344#47543344), then calculate area of cutted (left) part of square (note - we can obtain triangle, trapezoid, right-angled pantagon) and get your percent as ratio of area/square_area

Comment: MBo!  You reign supreme!  It will take me some time to understand and implement, but after studying your reply a few times I do understand your strategy of calculating the area of the cutted part and dividing it by the square area.  Not within grasp for me, yet, but within reach.  Brilliant!  And thank you!