# Find at what point you will reach image border while walking from a certain point at a certain angle

Tags: python, math, image-processing, trigonometry

I am doing some image processing and let us say that I have a point (e.g. (1000, 1000)) and an angle (e.g. 30 degrees), and I need to figure out at what point will I touch the border of the image (0, y) or (0, x) if I walked from that point at given angle. I can do it iteratively by just doing through an iterator and walking one step at a time, by doing in this example:

```
for i in range:
    x = 1000 - i * cos(30)
    y = 1000 - i * sin(30)
```

but maybe there is a better way to straight up find at which point will I hit the image border?
I added image for clarity.[image]

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542004/how-to-calculate-the-distance-from-a-given-point-on-the-surface-of-a-square-to-i/47543344#47543344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call `(x0, y0) = (1000, 1000)` your starting point.

Assuming you already know that the intersection point will be on the upper side of the box, then you are looking for a point `(x, 0)` such that `cotan(alpha) = (x - x0) * y0`.

So you can just choose `x = x0 + cotan(alpha) / y0`.

Trigonometry function `cotan` isn't directly part of python's standard library, but `cotan(alpha) = tan(pi/2 - alpha)`, so you can write:

```py
import math

x = x0 + math.tan(math.pi / 2 - alpha) / y0  # angle alpha in radians
```

Or alternatively:

```py
import math

x = x0 + math.tan((90 - alpha_in_degrees) * math.pi / 180) / y0
```

If your box is defined by coordinates `(left, right, top, bottom) = (0, ?, 0, ?)`, then you can check that the point was indeed on the top side of the box by checking that the calculated value for `x` is in range, and that `alpha` is between 0 and 180°:

```py
assert(left <= x <= right and 0 <= alpha_in_degrees <= 180)
```

Answer (score 0):

Time for some trigonometry, consider triangle like below

```
+
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
|   a\
+-----+
```

its height is known to be `1000`, its width is unknown, so denote it by `x` and value of angle `a` is known. `tan` function value is defined as ratio between opposite and adjacent in this case `tan(a) = 1000/x` which is equivalent to `tan(a)*x = 1000` which is equivalent to `x = 1000/tan(a)`.

After finding `x` rememeber you needs to subtract it from 1000, as your computing position in relation to (1000,1000)

Comment: Shouldn't it be cotan?

Comment: @Stef so far I know *the tangent of an angle is the length of the opposite side divided by the length of the adjacent side* can you provide document which obsoletes this definition?

Comment: No, this definition appears to be correct. But judging by the image the OP provided, I think it's cotan(alpha) that's relevant here.